# Codewars - Execution Timed Out (12000 ms) How do I improve?

Tags: javascript

How do I improve the performance? It says "Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)", so that I can't submit my solution.

This is the instruction:
A perfect number is a number in which the sum of its divisors (excluding itself) are equal to itself. Write a function that can verify if the given integer n is a perfect number, and return True if it is, or return False if not.

Examples
n = 28 has the following divisors: 1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28
1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28 therefore 28 is a perfect number, so you should return True

```
function isPerfect(n) {
  let factorSum = 0
  for(let i=1; i<n; i++){
   if(n%i ==0){
    factorSum+=i
  }
}
  return factorSum ===n? true:false
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to check for divisors greater than n/2

Comment: If the question is how to improve performance, the n/2 change suggested by @James seems to result in a +25 percent improvement.

Comment: Yes, I changed the code. But still says "Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)" https://www.codewars.com/kata/56a28c30d7eb6acef700004d/

Comment: Looking through the discussions on that kata, it looks like users have been seeing timeouts for years. If I had to guess, it's the tests causing the problems, not everyone's code.

Comment: I agree with Zac Anger: `var startTime = performance.now(); console.log(isPerfect(28)); var endTime = performance.now(); console.log(\`Call took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds\`);` takes less than 1ms to run in JS Bin; The idea it takes > 12 seconds is ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too slow, you need to find a faster algorithm. One trick with code wars is using console.log() to find the biggest solutions. I was getting ~10^11, which is unattainable in O(n). Also, if you ever use `bool?true:false`, it is unnecessary.

Hint for solution:

> You only need to check from 2-> n^0.5